# Is there a simple proof that the matrix is diagonalizable?

Tags: matrices, diagonalization

Let

$A^n=D$, where $D$ is a diagonal invertible matrix, and $n\ne0$ is a real number. Is there a simple proof (without involving Jordan canonical form) that the matrix $A$ is diagonalizable?

Comment: Are you implicitly assuming that the matrix has complex entries? Otherwise this is not true.

Comment: What do you mean with _diagonal invertible matrix_? A matrix that is both diagonal and invertible? Because then it is trivial..

Comment: @EricS. How is it trivial if it does not work over fields that are not algebraically closed?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen, Aah, I misread it as $A=D^n$. My bad!

Comment: @ Crostul: Yes I assume that the matrix has complex entries. Moreover, I assume that the matrices have finite dimension (if it matters).

Answer (score 1):

As $A$ and $D$ commute, eigenspaces of $D$ are stable by $A$. The vector space is therefore a (finite) direct sum of vectors spaces $E_\lambda$ such taht he restriction of $A$ to $E_\lambda$ satisfies $A^n=\lambda. Id$. This restriction is diagonalizable as the polynomial $x^n-\lambda$ has simple roots. Putting together bases of diagonalization of $A$ restricted to the $E_\lambda$ yields a diagonal base for $A$.

Comment: Does it work also for non-integer $n$? Besides I do not find the proof simple.

Comment: For $n$ non integer, this has no meaning. The proof however works perfectly in infinite dimensional case.